# Variables with a dash

Tags: puppet

In puppet, modules can have a dash in their name, and thus variables can, too. But then, how can we use such variables?

For example, I have a `$ssh_mode` variable defined in a `google-authenticator::params` class, so I expect to be able to call `$google-authenticator::params::ssh_mode`, but puppet (0.25.5) cuts on the dash. Using `${google-authenticator::params::ssh_mode}` doesn't help either.

What can I do to access this variable?

Comment: I don't suppose the clean and obvious "don't use dashes in your module names" is going to cut it?

Comment: Well, that's what I was wondering. According to @m0dlx's answer, I will have to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find this works in later versions.  Certainly in Puppet 2.7, the variable interpolation in strings now includes dashes (which also causes a few compatibility issues).

The deeper problem though is you're relying on undefined handling of modules with dashes in.  I'd strongly suggest you rename the module to use an underscore, or no separator.  There are many bugs in Puppet (that come and go between different major versions) if you don't stick to this recommendation:

> Class names, module names, and the names of defined and custom resource types should be restricted to lowercase alphanumeric characters and underscores, and should begin with a lowercase letter; that is, they should match the expression [a-z][a-z0-9_]*. Although some names that violate these restrictions currently work, using them is not recommended.

From [Language Guide (Reserved Words & Acceptable Characters)](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html#reserved-words--acceptable-characters).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a page describing the [allowed characters](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Allowed_Characters_in_Identifier_Names) in puppet identifiers.

Under class names section, you can read:

```
 …but if you use any hyphens, you screw up qualified variable access.
```

Under variables section, you can read:

```
* [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ (No unicode nonsense or %@^ etc.)
* i.e. no hyphens, ever.
```